# Is it Possible to Draw a Triple Border only on one side of a Rectangle?

Tags: html, css, border

I would like to have a Triple Border only one side of a rectangle Without using an Extra Html tag.The Code I have tried so far is Given Below.

**Method#1**

```css
#element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #000, 0 0 0 6px #f00, 0 0 0 9px #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

**Method#2**

```css
#element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black; /* inner border */
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 15px black; /* outer 'border' */
  outline: 12px solid green; /* fill */
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

But this can be only use in case if you need Triple Border on all Sides,Instead Of that I only needs the Triple Border on One side.Is it Possible?.Please Help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this CSS Property

```
box-shadow: 5px 0px 0 0px #000, 10px 0px 0 0px #f00, 15px 0px 0px 0px #000;
```

```css
#element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 0 0px #000, 10px 0px 0 0px #f00, 15px 0px 0px 0px #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

Comment: @DreamHunter Welcome Mate

Answer (score 1):

You can use `before` and `after` to achieve this.

```css
#element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-right: 5px solid black; /* inner border */
  /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 15px black; */ /* outer 'border' */
  /* outline: 12px solid green; */ /* fill */
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.triple-right {
  position: relative;
}
.triple-right:before, .triple-right:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 5px;
}
.triple-right:before {
  background-color: green;
  right: -10px;
}
.triple-right:after {
  background-color: black;
  right: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="element" class="triple-right"></div>
```

Comment: Happy Coding :) @DreamHunter

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea using gradient:

```css
#element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) right/ 5px 100%,
    linear-gradient(red,red)   right/ 10px 100%,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) right/ 15px 100%;
    /*And so on if you want more border*/
    
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```